# VSCode CLI install extension from local file with powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use PowerShell to install a VSCode extension from a local file (not from the internet).

When I use Start-Process and give the appropriate file path, it opens VSCode, stalls the script, and does not install the extension.  When I close VSCode, the script terminates without error, but still the extensions is not installed.

I need the exact syntax to install a VSCode extension from PowerShell silently (no new window).

I've tried just about every syntax variation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Start-Process`, call the default name for VS Code: `code`. VS Code has some [nice CLI options when you call this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions), one of which is `--install-extension`. Heres an example of what you can call in powershell or in a `.ps1` script that would do this:

```
code --install-extension path/to/extension.ts
```

or if you have made an [extension pack to help automate the install of multiple extensions at once](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/03/07/extension-pack-roundup#_how-do-i-make-an-extension-pack):

```
code --install-extension path/to/extensionPack.vsix
```